# Elevate corporate network write access privileges within application as required

Tags: security, networking

We have customer project files on a network drive.  Most users do not have write access privileges within some of the directories.  I have been tasked with finding a way to allow them to create directories and files programmatically through a user front end we have developed without allowing them to manually make changes by going to the directory in windows explorer.  Most of these users do not have local admin rights, nor would that change their network admin privileges.

This is in a .net programming environment.

I see numerous examples for elevating local rights, but none for elevating network rights.

Some options:
-elevate the privileges within the application.
-run an application on the/a server where the server has the necessary rights and performs the necessary task(s).
-create a windows service application that will run on the server with a listener that will receive requests and perform the necessary task(s).

The second two options would require significant hoops to jump through as my company has a very strict IM security policy.  The first option would be ideal, but I am not sure it is possible.  I'm not sure the second option is possible either for that matter.

Any thoughts or input would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use Impersonation.

RE:  [How do you do Impersonation in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net)

Just make sure the credentials you are using for Impersonation have rights to the folders as necessary.  You can use domain or local on the file server credentials as necessary.